# Child settlement in uk

Tags: uk-citizenship

I am a British by descent and my child born outside the uk. Now I am in uk with my child, how do I apply for my child's settlement. Which is the most suitable way and quick too. Please help

Comment: What is the child's status at the moment. How long have you lived in the UK with the child?

Answer (score 2):

Your child can get British citizenship in the following ways:

- **Register under section 3(2):** To qualify for this, you need to have a parent (the child's grandparent) who was a British citizen otherwise than by descent, and you need to have lived in the UK for a period of 3 years some time in your life before the child's birth, during which you were not absent for more than 270 days. The child becomes a British citizen by descent.
- **Register under section 3(5):** To qualify for this, the child and both parents must have been living in the UK for the 3 years immediately preceding the application. The child becomes a British citizen otherwise than by descent.

Since your child is already in the UK, if you plan to be there for a while (at least 3 years), section 3(5) has the slight advantage that the child becomes a British citizen otherwise than by descent, so won't have the same problem you had in transmitting British citizenship to children born abroad in the future.

Comment: Thanku. Could unguided me further how  long time procedure is and also what if my husband is not joining us here and will join in few years time. I want the process to be done now.

Comment: Also what about the procedure of settlement? Indefinite leave to remain and then nationality?